# What's the arrow symbol in the spray.io lib for?

Tags: spray

I had a look at the classes in the spray.io library and often stumpled upon the arrow symbol "`⇒`". What does this symbol mean and where do I find documentation about it's meaning?

Comment: It has the same meaning as the arrow consisting of two characters `=>` which is standard element of the Scala language. It's used in function values and types and in the match/case expression (and maybe somewhere else I'm currently forgetting about).

Comment: Okay thanks, so is this similiar to a type alias, and more interestingly: why do you not use the standard arrow? Is there a reason (e.g. extended Features etc)?

Comment: No real reason, just for aesthetic reasons. We use the common automatic  source code formatter scalariform which automatically converts the supported ascii sequences to the corresponding unicode characters while building.